# Cannot create Elasticsearch instance in AWS using Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-cloudformation, aws-elasticsearch

Im trying to create an Elasticsearch instance in AWS using cloudformation, but cannot create and shows this error,

**Creating Elasticsearch Domain did not stabilize.**,

Here is the cloudformation template,

```
  Elasticsearch:
    Type: AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain
    Properties:
      DomainName: !Ref ElasticsearchDomainName
      AccessPolicies:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              AWS: '*'
            Action:
              - 'es:*'
            Condition:
              IpAddress:
                'aws:SourceIp':
                  - 12.34.56.78/32
            Resource: '*'
      ElasticsearchVersion: !Ref ElasticsearchVersion 
      ElasticsearchClusterConfig:
        InstanceCount: !Ref InstanceCount 
        InstanceType: t2.small.elasticsearch
      EBSOptions:
        EBSEnabled: true
        VolumeSize: 25
      NodeToNodeEncryptionOptions:
        Enabled: true
      AdvancedOptions:
        rest.action.multi.allow_explicit_index: 'true'
        indices.fielddata.cache.size: !Ref "AWS::NoValue"
    UpdatePolicy:
      EnableVersionUpgrade: true
```

It seems this issue has been already mentioned here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44019483/creating-elasticsearch-service-with-aws-cloudformation-creating-elasticsearch) , but it didn't worked for me

```
AdvancedOptions:
       rest.action.multi.allow_explicit_index: 'true'
       indices.fielddata.cache.size: ""
```

even adding that failing for me, What else be the issue,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What issue? What error are you getting exactly?

Comment: "Creating Elasticsearch Domain did not stabilize", is showing in cloudformation, and its taking hours to fail

Comment: It is working when I've updated the instance type to t3.small.elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me with the following template:

```
Resources:
  Elasticsearch:
    Type: AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain
    Properties:
      AdvancedOptions:
        indices.fielddata.cache.size: ''
        rest.action.multi.allow_explicit_index: 'true'
      DomainEndpointOptions:
        CustomEndpoint: 'mycustomdomain.com'
        CustomEndpointCertificateArn: '{{resolve:ssm:my-cert-arn:1}}'
        CustomEndpointEnabled: true
        EnforceHTTPS: true
      DomainName: 'logs'
      ElasticsearchVersion: 7.10
      ElasticsearchClusterConfig:
        InstanceCount: 1
        InstanceType: t3.small.elasticsearch
      EBSOptions:
        EBSEnabled: true
        VolumeSize: 25
    UpdatePolicy:
      EnableVersionUpgrade: true
```

Comment: Yea, it works with t3.small.elasticsearch but When I use t2.small.elasticsearch It is not working.